# Creating strings and arrays

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to create a information based application, I have 92 subjects, for these subjects I have 92 map locations and maybe as much as 400 url links.  Currently I have created a class for each map location and a class for each url link, but this would mean I would have in excess of 500 classes, so what I want to do is split the subjects in four catergories ie. listview of about 23 in four tabs which I have done and create a class that gets the url based on the selection the use makes and do the same for the map locations.

Do I need to put these in a xml using the id method and how do you call individual entries, i.e. would I need 500 android:id, is there an easier way?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would it be possible to make a general class to hold data, and maybe keeping data in a file or even a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd save all that data into a SQLite database. That will allow you manipulate and retrieve each map location easily, and you can use the ID of those as the primary key. There are tons of examples of how to use SQLite on Android... Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use any database then retrieve elements accordingly.